# Very small coefficients

Tags: predictor

Suppose that you are running a linear regression model with outcome $Y$ and explanatory variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. You also run a linear regression model with a quadratic transformation of $X_1$:  $$E[Y] = \beta_0 + \beta_{1}X_{1}+\beta_{2}X_{1}^{2} + \beta_{3}X_{2}$$

If $|\beta_2| \approx 0$ can we drop it from our model?

Comment: The key is not the absolute size of an estimated coefficient but how that compares with its standard error. The units of measurement of $\beta_2$ here are (units of $Y$)/(units of $X$ squared) and one reason the estimate could appear small is just using particular units. In particular, comparing it with the estimate of $\beta_1$ or $\beta_3$ is unsound unless you consider differences in units. If any coefficient appears very small, it might be practical to change the units, although no statistical point is implied or raised thereby.

Comment: Agree with the comment of @NickCox. For instance, you may change the unit from kilometer to nanometer, and the coefficient will become tiny. Compared to whether it's close to zero it's more crucial to examine if such magnitude is meaningful given the units of $Y$ and $X_1$. Also, it would be very helpful to explain your research question and the p-value of $\beta_2$ in your question text.